# How can I find my house in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find my house. It keeps taking me to something else I have done, but I can't find my mansion (my house) that I am working on. I really need to finish it before my friend comes over this weekend. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find your house and don't remember its cordinates the best possible solution I can think of is to go into creative mode and fly around until you recognize the landscape.

If it is near where you spawned in the game, just kill yourself with /kill or jumping of a cliff.

If you slept in a bed in that mansion, the bed will be your spawn and all you need to do is kill yourself.

If this is not the case, next time sleep in a bed before you start working.

Comment: I am on creative mode already, and I have a bed in my mansion, but it keeps taking me to the first thing I built. So, basically, that answer does NOT help me! Besides, I am minecraft miles away! And Raven is not my real name, but I wish it was, so I used it.

Comment: did you sleep in your bed?

Comment: Yes, yes I have.

Comment: type /kill into the chat box